# How to deploy a Kotlin application to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, kotlin

How can I deploy a kotlin application to Heroku? I have tried, but it isn't deploying!

Thanks!

Comment: A Kotlin application can be deployed in the same way as a Java application. What did you try and what problems did you face?

Comment: Try this one: https://jkutner.github.io/2017/04/10/kotlin-heroku-ktor.html This link is from official kotlin docs pdf.

Comment: if you wants to deploy ktor app on heroku .. please read this medium blog on ktor app deployment https://nameisjayant.medium.com/deploy-ktor-app-with-postgresql-on-heroku-ff35df4b5c55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy a Java application, than convert the main class to Kotlin and start from there.